# Is it possible for a :map to insert text without fold-closing the inserted text AND leaving the other folds as they are?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, folding

I am facing the following problem: a function, triggered by a `:nnoremap` inserts a few lines into a buffer. Since I have folding enabled with `foldexpr=...` and the inserted text contains this expression, the inserted text is folded.

I could stop this unwanted behaviour by setting `nofoldenable`. Yet, if I do that, the already existing folds are opened. This is also not what I want. The existing folds should stay as the are, opened or closed.

So, is it possible to tell vim somehow that the inserted text is to be inserted without trying to fold it?

Comment: What happens if, after insertion, you add a `:silent! :normal! zO` inside your function?

Comment: @VanLaser `zO` and friends work recursively on folds under the cursor, but inserting text in a function doesn't necessarily happen at the cursor position (`append()`, for instance, appends by line number and doesn't move the cursor; neither does it set the `'[`,`']` marks).

Comment: @Rene I think my answer should be a working solution. Am I wrong?

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg I am currently in a foreign country and don't have my development computer with me, so that I cannot check if it works for me. Please allow me another week until I'll come back to your answer. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily disable the `foldexpr` by setting `foldmethod` to `manual` during the execution of the function. You could do this in your function like this:

```
function! MyMappedFunction(...)
  let l:foldmethod=&foldmethod 
  setlocal foldmethod=manual

  " ... function content ...

  let foldmethod=l:foldmethod
end function
```

Note that the old `foldmethod` is saved in order to restore it after the function is finished.

Comment: I would also save the configured `foldmethod` before overriding it, this way you could restore the previous configuration automatically.

Comment: Because of other problems with updating folds and because of a bug(?) in Vim for insert mode+expression folding I always do this when entering insert mode and restore when leaving insert mode or leaving the window, see http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3128/is-there-a-way-to-disable-the-foldexpr-during-autocomplete

Comment: Thanks @Nobe4, I noticed your comment but I forgot to update afterwords.